# Euler-Cauchy equation prove

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

to find solution of $x^2y'' + axy' + by =x^n$

use Method of Undetermined Coefficents ,

prove particular solution is $y=Cx^n$

(Hint : use $x=e^z$)

How to prove??

Answer (score 0):

You just insert the trial function,
$$
C(n(n-1)+an+b)x^n=x^n,
$$
so that if $n^2+(a-1)n+b\ne 0$ there is one $C=(n^2+(a-1)n+b)^{-1}$ that renders the trial into an inhomogeneous or particular solution.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, but I want to use $x=e^z$ permutation....

Comment: Then define $u(z)=y(e^z)$ and compute the derivatives of $u$ and compare with the differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

$$x=e^z \implies z=\ln x$$
Now find the derivatives w.r.t $z$:
$$y'=\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac {dy}{dz}\dfrac {dz}{dx}=\frac 1 x\dfrac {dy}{dz}$$
Do the dame for the second derivative:
$$y''=\dfrac {d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac {d}{dx}\left (\dfrac {dy}{dx} \right)=\dfrac {d}{dx}\left (\frac 1 x\dfrac {dy}{dz}\right)$$
$$y''=-\dfrac 1 {x^2}\dfrac {dy}{dz}+\dfrac 1x\dfrac {d}{dz}\left (\dfrac {dy}{dz}\right)\dfrac {dz}{dx}$$
$$y''=-\dfrac 1 {x^2}\dfrac {dy}{dz}+\dfrac 1{x^2} \dfrac {d^2y}{dz^2}$$
Plug these results in your original DE and solve it.